# Duplicate name on form inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, input, duplicates

I have a div that contains some inputs from a form:

```
<div class="guides_chapters_container" id="cdefault" style="">
                <div class="guides_chapters_ctitle">
                <input class="guides_chapters_input" name="gtitle" type="text" value="">
                    <div class="guides_chapters_upguide" onclick="javascript: guide_cmoveup(event);"></div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_downguide" onclick="javascript: guide_cmovedown(event);"></div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_deleteguide" onclick="javascript: guide_cdelete(event);"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="guides_chapters_bar">
                    <center>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" style="font-weight:bold;" onclick="surround('[b]', '[/b]');">B</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" style="font-style:italic;" onclick="surround('[i]', '[/i]');">i</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" style="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="surround('[u]', '[/u]');">u</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" onclick="surround('[title]', '[/title]');">Título</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" onclick="surround('[center]', '[/center]');">Centrar</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" onclick="showdiv('guideimages'); ">Image</div>
                    <div class="guides_chapters_button" onclick="javascript: guide_bimages(event);">Big Image</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <textarea class="guides_chapters_textarea" id="textarea" name="gmessage" rows="7" cols="25"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and im using this to replicate this div:

```
function add() {
    var item = $('#cdefault').clone();
    item.attr({'style': ''});
    $('#ccontainer').append(item);
}
```

Everything works, but my problem is that now that input (gtitle and gmessage) share the same name and wont post correctly. Is there any way to add that name after I clone? or anything to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the container 'ccontainer' and where is you call of the method 'add()'?

Comment: You need to resolve duplicate IDs within the page too.

Comment: thats not an issue. I call the method add in a button, that works pretty well. My problem is the workaround on that input form. Some people said that I should rename gmessage and gtittle with [] after. but then how to work that on the post?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the original and the clone's element have the same name. Try to change the elements name of the clone.

```
function add() {
   var item = $('#cdefault').clone();
   item.attr({'style': ''});
   $('#ccontainer').append(item);
   $('#ccontainer input[name="gtitle"]').attr('name', 'gtitle');
   $('#ccontainer textarea[name="gmessage"]').attr('name', 'gmessage');
}
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for

With incrementation every time function is called

```
var x=1;
function add() {
   var item = $('#cdefault').clone();
   item.attr({'style': ''});
   $('#ccontainer').append(item);
   $('#ccontainer input[name="gtitle"]').attr('name', 'gtitle'+x);
   $('#ccontainer textarea[name="gmessage"]').attr('name', 'gmessage'+x);
   x+=1;
}
```

Comment: Can I do that with increment? so that gtitle and gmessage increase each time add is called?

Comment: `code`$('#cdefault input[id="gtitle1"]').attr('name', $xpto);
    $('#cdefault textarea[id="gmessage1"]').attr('name',$xpto2);
 `$('#cdefault input[name="$xpto"]').attr('id', $xpto);
    $('#cdefault textarea[name="$xpto2"]').attr('id', $xpto2);`code` if u can fix this im done :P

Comment: Check it out I added new function for incrementation. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to change here '#ccontainer input[name="gtitle"]' to a variable?

Comment: I wanted something like this:  $('#cdefault input[id="gtitle1"]').attr('name', xpto);
    $('#cdefault textarea[id="gmessage1"]').attr('name',xpto2);
 $('#cdefault input[name=' + xpto + ']').attr('id', xpto);
    $('#cdefault textarea[name=' + xpto2 + ']').attr('id', xpto2);

Comment: fixed. the append had to come after we changed for some reason :O

Comment: nvm its not fixed. it just works for 2 clones. for the original and the next one. not more than that :x